Why does this compiler optimization only occur outside of main?
I have the following C function which multiples two unsigned shorts together and stores the result into an unsigned integer. This function then prints whether the resulting value has the most significant bit set or not.
void unsigned_short_mult_test(unsigned short a, unsigned short b) {
    unsigned int x = a * b;
    
    if (x >= 0x80000000)
        printf("%u >= %u", x, 0x80000000);
    else
        printf("%u < %u", x, 0x80000000);
}

For the test, I pass the value of 65535 for a and b in main():
int main() {
    unsigned short a = 65535;
    unsigned short b = 65535;
    unsigned_short_mult_test(a, b);

    return 0;
}

With compiler optimizations enabled (-O1 or above), this always prints "incorrectly":
4294836225 < 2147483648
However, this makes sense to me because it seems like the compiler promotes a and b to integers during the multiplication, then casts the result back into an unsigned integer to be stored in x. The optimization assumes the product of two integers cannot be larger than the maximum value of an integer and simply removes the first part of the if statement from the resulting machine code. However, when I place the same code into main, this optimization does not occur:
int main() {
    unsigned short a = 65535;
    unsigned short b = 65535;

    // The same code as unsigned_short_mult_test
    unsigned int x = a * b;
    
    if (x >= 0x80000000)
        printf("%u >= %u", x, 0x80000000);
    else
        printf("%u < %u", x, 0x80000000);

    return 0;
}

This prints the correct result: 4294836225 >= 2147483648
Why does this optimization only seem to occur in the function but not when done directly in main?

@DavisHerring: Re “Why try to understand it?”:  Because the behavior specified by the C standard is not the only aspect of computer behavior we are interested in. Understanding behavior beyond what the C standard specifies is useful for debugging, optimization, and more.

Try unsigned int x = (unsigned int)a * b; Shorts are promoted to int only after multiplying during assignment.

It's not "only within a function". main() is a function too. The difference here is the difference between arguments and local variables initialized to constants.

"Understanding behavior beyond what the C standard specifies is useful for debugging, optimization, and more." - Really?  If you write code that depends on undefined behavior, it could break the next time you change compiler version, when you run the code on different hardware, when the computer is under (different) load, when the wind changes direction.  If your need for performance is so critical that you have to write code with undefined behavior, you probably should be coding the performance critical parts in assembly language!

@StephenC: Re “Really?”: Yes, really. Different errors in code manifest various symptoms, and knowledge and experience of the behavior of the compiler (and the operating system, the processor, and more) makes those symptoms into clues about the errors. Erroneous data in memory, segment violations, and mistaken output are symptoms of different things. Debugging with such knowledge is faster, and hence cheaper, than randomly guessing what an error might be. Consider that virtually everything a debugger shows its user is undefined by the C standard but is ver valuable for debugging.

@StephenC: Re “If you write code that depends on undefined behavior, it could break the next time you change compiler version”: This is a mischaracterization of what “undefined behavior” as specified by the C standard is, and it should not be taught. The C standard leaves some things undefined because the authors had no sensible definition to provide, others because there were sensible definitions but they differed between implementations, others because they were intended to be up to implementations to define if they desired, and others because they are the domain of other specifications…

… So it is incorrect to push the idea that “undefined behavior” is behavior that must or should be avoided or that it can change randomly. “Undefined behavior” only means “not covered by the C standard.” Some of it is defined by other documents and will not change randomly. And even much that is not specified is nonetheless a consequence of compiler design and largely follows predictable patterns that are useful for diagnosing bugs.

Normally the optimizer first eliminates the function call by inlining the function, then eliminates the multiplication by calculating the result up front.  That calculation is not subject to the same overflow behavior.  But with -O1 that can't happen, inlining produces more code, so the multiplication removal can't happen either.

Probably not the issue here, but IIRC, one reason why main can get optimized differently from other functions is that some implementations will treat it as a "cold" function since it can only be called once. (Yes, technically it can be called recursively but that's hardly ever done).  As such, they may optimize it for size rather than speed.

Inside the unsigned_short_mult_test function, the compiler does not know what argument values will be passed, and it performs an abstract analysis. Likely, the analysis determines that the only cases with defined behavior are those for which x has a nonnegative int value, and therefore the compiler may generate code as if the high bit of x is never set.
Inside main, the compiler knows what values are being used and evaluates the arithmetic using those concrete values. It likely multiplies 65,535 by 65,535, allowing the result to wrap (4,294,836,225 as unsigned, −131,071 as int) with no regard to the fact the behavior is not defined by the C standard), and determining x will have the value 4,294,836,225. This value has the high bit set, so the compiler generates code on that basis.
These behaviors depend on compiler features and optimization options. The above is an explanation for what happened in the particular circumstances you explored, but the behaviors may vary in other circumstances.
